# Read a pariticular section of list seperated by a delimiter into an array using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, ksh

I have a command which outputs in the following pattern

```
red
yellow
blue
green
--------
black
brown
pink
```

I would like to read the list before "----" into one array and the other half into another array.

I know that this can be done using a loop. But also I think that this can be done very elegantly by using SED or AWK and the problem is that I don't know how. I would really appreciate any help with this. I am very confident that it is possible but please let me know if i am wrong or is there a better/smarter way.

Comment: Post your attempt and with where you are blocked.

Comment: Also this is not a neat way, post process command output like this only if you have no other way to control this with your original command.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the origin of this question. What's your actual use case? Can we get some confirmation that (once you ask a real question) it's not an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ?

Comment: I understand you want to create a Bash array.  You cannot create a Bash array with `awk` or `sed`, aside from, well, reading their output.  And if you want to split their output in two arrays, you will still need to read their output line by line to detect your separator line, irrespective of how you intend to create the arrays.  It is likely that your best solution will involve some kind of loop or line-per-line parsing.

Comment: I need to qualify my previous comment : you could achieve what you want by reading the input twice, and using `sed`/`awk` to return the lines before the separator on the first run, and the lines after the separator on the second run, and perform two separate assignments.

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading the entire list into *one* array.

```
readarray -t tmp < <(yourCommand)
```

Then search for the delimiter.

```
for ((i=0; i<${#tmp[@]}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${tmp[i]} == "--------" ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Then use substring expansion to split the array into two pieces. Note that if the delimiter isn't found, every element will go into `one`, leaving `two` empty.

```
one=("${tmp[@]:0:i}")
two=("${tmp[@]:i+1}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer more like this:

```
$cat txt
red
yellow
blue
green
--------
black
brown
pink
```

then:

```
array=$(cat txt | awk '{ if ($1~/----/) exit; else {print $1}}')
echo $array

red
yellow
blue
green
```

Answer (score 1):

**If your file would be this**

```
red
yellow
blue
green
--------
black
brown
pink
```

Then you can:

```
 $ array=$(cat file | grep -v - | tr '\n' ' ')
 $
 $ echo $array
 $ red yellow blue green black brown pink
 $
 $ echo ${array:0:21}
 $ red yellow blue green
 $
 $ echo ${array:22:-1}
 $ black brown pink
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="" } {s=$i" "s } END { split(s,a,"--------"); print a [1],a[2]  } ' d

red
yellow
blue
green

black
brown
pink
```

a[1] is the top portion. 
a[2] is the bottom portion.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will read line by line until the delimiter, appending each line to the first array, and create the second array with one command.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a array1=()
while IFS= read -r line ; do
  [[ $line != "--------" ]] || break
  array1+=("$line")
done
readarray -t array2
```

It needs to receive its input on standard in.  Put it in a script (say split_arrays), make it executable, and call it like this:

```
./split_arrays < <(command)
```

Or :

```
./split_arrays <data_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need actually any kind of loops to process the file.
These two commands will do the trick:

```
sed -n '1,/-----/!p' a.txt #Will exclude 1st line up to pattern, excluding also the line with pattern = last part of your file
sed -n '/-----/,$!p' a.txt #Will exclude pattern line up to last line excluding also the line with pattern = first part of your file
```

You can then assign them to different arrays with readarray technique:

```
readarray -t first < <(sed -n '/-----/,$!p' a.txt)
readarray -t second < <(sed -n '1,/-----/!p' a.txt)
```